# Unwanted text appearing over JButton when hovering over it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am well aware that I'm not suppose to use a null layout. However, for the moment I'm using it to test something. My program is simple enough: Press the Mexico button to have the Diplo button appear. The issue is when I scroll my mouse over the Diplo button after it appears, the mex button text appears over it. I'm currently assuming my problem somehow involves either the null layout, not using the paintcomponent, or something with the methods, though I'm unsure of what it could be that's going wrong.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class PanelTest extends JPanel
{
//Country Lists
public Country Mex = new Country("Mexico","Empire",15);
public Country Sel;
//Country buttons
public JButton buttonMex;
//Foreign Choices
private JButton buttonAggro;
public JButton buttonDip; 
private JButton buttonEspo;

public PanelTest(){
  setLayout(null);
   //Definitions for button
  buttonDip = new JButton();
  buttonDip.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
  buttonDip.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
  buttonDip.setText("Diplo");
  buttonDip.addActionListener(new DipListener());
  buttonDip.setSize(100, 50);
  buttonDip.setLocation(0,100);
  buttonDip.setBorder(null);
  buttonDip.setOpaque(false);
  buttonDip.setContentAreaFilled(false);
  buttonDip.setBorderPainted(false);
  buttonDip.setFocusPainted(false);
  add(buttonDip); 
  buttonDip.setEnabled(false);
  buttonDip.setVisible(false);

  buttonMex = new JButton();
  buttonMex.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
  buttonMex.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
  buttonMex.setText("Mexico");
  buttonMex.addActionListener(new MexListener());
  buttonMex.setSize(100, 50);
  buttonMex.setLocation(0,0);
  buttonMex.setBorder(null);
  buttonMex.setOpaque(false);
  buttonMex.setContentAreaFilled(false);
  buttonMex.setBorderPainted(false);
  buttonMex.setFocusPainted(false);
  add(buttonMex); 
  buttonMex.setEnabled(false);
  buttonMex.setVisible(false);
  //MAIN 
  buttonValid();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
}
public void buttonValid(){
      if(Mex.getVal() == true){
      buttonMex.setEnabled(true);
      buttonMex.setVisible(true);
  }
}
public void FTest()
{
       buttonMex.setEnabled(false);
       buttonMex.setVisible(false);
       buttonDip.setEnabled(true);
       buttonDip.setVisible(true);
}
  private class MexListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    FTest();  
    Sel = Mex; 
  }
}
private class DipListener implements ActionListener
 {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
     Mex.setRel(-30);
   }
 }
```

Here's a photo of what my program produces

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhzQN.png]

Answer (score 1):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
}
```

Don't override paintComponent(). There is no reason to have an empty method. Get rid of that code:

The background of the panel will never get cleared when you do this and you can have painting artifacts.